# How to write a formula using box product

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Can anybody help in writing the following formula... I am having trouble. LHS I can write, but not the RHS.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `\DeclareMathOperator*` from `amsmath` to declare an operator accepting "limits" in super/sub script positions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\MyS}{\text{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\scalebox{1.25}{$\square$}}}}
\newcommand\Osq{\mathbin{\text{\scalebox{.84}{$\square$}}}}

\begin{document}

\[
G_1\Osq G_2\Osq \cdots \Osq G_n = \MyS_{i=1}^{n}G_i.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **egreg** comments, perhaps one could use `\vcenter` instead of an explicit dimension in the definition of `\MyS`; in this way, the square will be vertically centered with respect to the equal sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\MyS}{\vcenter{\hbox{\text{\scalebox{1.3}{$\square$}}}}}
\newcommand\Osq{\mathbin{\text{\scalebox{.84}{$\square$}}}}

\begin{document}

\[
G_1\Osq G_2\Osq \cdots \Osq G_n = \MyS_{i=1}^{n}G_i.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also the use of `\mathbin` in the definition of `\Osq` to have the proper spacing for a binary operator.

Comment: even though the normal-sized box is baseline-aligned, setting the enlarged box on the baseline doesn't look right.  shifting it down a bit (perhaps with the top aligned at cap height) would look much better.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Agreed. I lowered just a bit. I hope it's better now.

Comment: @barbarabeeton in fact, I also reduced the size of the square used as binary operator; I think it looks better this way.

Comment: Probably using `\vcenter` is better than using an explicit dimension: `\vcenter{\hbox{\text{\scalebox{1.25}{$\square$}}}}`

Comment: @egreg yes, great suggestion. Thanks. I've added it to my answer. Looking at both possibilities I still can't decide which one I like better :-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Your `1.1pt` will be used in all styles; probably an `ex` based dimension together with `\text` would be better.

Comment: @egreg again, you're right :-) I've edited with your suggestion.

Comment: @egreg do you think that `\vcenter`ing the small binary squares is also a good call?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I don't think so.